# Multiple yearling badge on the same year

Tags: discussion, badges

After reading about this badge I found out that you can get it multiple times, but as my understanding  only once per year.

This month i got the yearling badge two times,I find it weird to git this badge two times in the same year, is this a bug.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 5):

You've been a member of Stack Overflow for many years.  You can get the Yearling badge for every year you are a member, if you earn at least 200 reputation for each year.  Since you recently gained a lot of reputation (to pass both 200 and 400 total) you earned the badge twice.  You'll earn another when you pass 600 reputation.